# Arduino / BitVoicer Sending IR code on loop

Tags: arduino-uno

I was designing a voice automated kitchen lighting system. I have led strips under the cabinets which are remote controlled by an IR remote, so I captured the IR codes and got an IR led to turn them on. Now I introduced BitVoicer so that I could use voice commands to control the LED. I have ran into the issue that the IR led keeps turning the lights on and off, but my IR codes worked prior to using BitVoicer.

Here is my arduino code:

```
#include <BitVoicer11.h>

int IRledPin = 13;

BitVoicerSerial bvSerial = BitVoicerSerial();

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(IRledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  bvSerial.getData();

  if(bvSerial.strData == "")
  {
    return;
  }

  if(bvSerial.strData == "wake")
  {
   LightOnCode();
  }
}

  void pulseIR(long microsecs)
   {
     cli();

     while (microsecs > 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(IRledPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(10);

        microsecs -= 26;
      }
     sei();
    }
   void LightOnCode()
{
  pulseIR(8940);
  delayMicroseconds(4380);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(600);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(560);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(540);
        delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(500);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(560);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(600);
  pulseIR(500);
  delayMicroseconds(580);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1640);
  pulseIR(580);
  delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1660);
  pulseIR(560);
  delayMicroseconds(560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(1680);
  pulseIR(520);

}
```

If anyone could answer my question as to why the led keeps sending extra signals I would appreciate it! If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the [Documentation](http://www.bitsophia.com/BitVoicer/v12/BitVoicerManual_v12_en.pdf) on page 22, it looks like you need to use your `bvSerial.strData` calls within a function called `void serialEvent()` rather than inside of your loop.  I would recommend trying out their tutorial on that page just to make sure you get BitVoicer to work properly before scaling it for your application.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thank you very much! I will try and mess around with it more tonight and post an update on the progress!